# Can I swap my hard drive from an intel/Nvidia system to an amd/radeon system?

Tags: hard-drive, swap, cpu, gpu

I am getting a new pc soon. My current rig is using a GTX 760 and Intel cpu. The new computer will be using an AMD cpu with a Radeon RX 6700 XT.

Will I have any issues swapping the hard drive over and is the anything I should prepare for aside from backing up important files?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 currently.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Please be sure to take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to get a better idea how Stack Exchange sites work.

Comment: Is install UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you will have to reinstall grub or use efibootmgr to add UEFI entry into new motherboard. And new system often require newer versions of Ubuntu. Best if Ubuntu is 6 mon to a year release after hardware released for ease of install.  Some require the very newest kernel & drivers and then 21.04 with perhaps even ppa for even newer kernel.

Comment: Maybe you can but it's not best practice. With a significant hardware change, you should reinstall the OS.  Otherwise your software has been installed and configured for your current hardware.  What's the point if buying new hardware only to have it optimized for your old hardware and crippled by configs that are no longer relevant?  Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the proprietary nVidia video driver, you'll need to switch to the FOSS video driver instead, else you'll get (at best) a command prompt, more likely a black screen after booting on the new hardware.  Other than that, everything should be okay, because Linux detects all hardware on each startup.